# Check if an element is in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

As far as I understood it from [this notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iS6U.png), if we have a cyclic group $G_q$ of order $q$, we can check if an element $a$ is included in this group, by checking if $a^q=1$. 
However, I do not understand how to apply this on a practical example: 
Say we have $q=7$ (and are using $g=3$ as our generator,) which would just result in the group
$G_7=\{3 = 3^1 \mod 7, 2 = 3^2 \mod 7, 6, 4, 5, 1\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. And checking if an element is included in $G_7$ can be simply done by $a<=O(G_7)=6$, but not by with $a^7 \mod 7=1$ holds. 

Therefore, I would be thankful if s.o. could provide me an example of checking if an element is in an exemplary cyclic group with the method from the above-linked notation or explain to me what I got wrong here.

Comment: You seem to be using $7$ for both $p$ and $q$, and as $q|(p-1)$ this can't be.

Comment: We could set $p=1373$ so that $q|(p-1)$ holds, but I don't quite understand how this then affects the group $G_7$.

Comment: For $\,q = 7\,$ the smallest prime $p$ with $\,q\mid p-1\,$ is $\,p=29,\,$ and the group $G$  is the group of $7$'th roots of $1$, whose least generators are $7$ (or $-4$), so $\, G_7 = \langle 7\rangle = \{ 7^k \} \equiv  \{1, 7, 20, 24, 23, 16, 25\}\pmod{\!29}.\,$ The choice of $p$ "affects the group $G_7$" because $G_7$ is a *subgroup* of $\,\Bbb Z_p^*,\,$ so the equality test $\,a^q = 1\,$ depends on *arithmetic in $\,\Bbb Z_p,\,$* which depends on $\,p.\ \ $

Comment: @cryptphil: you  have calculated the powers mod 7, not mod $p$. I sympathise with you, the notation chosen by your book is very poor.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you very much for your explanation; I already assumed that I haven't created my groups correctly... So for finding generators for the "group of 7th roots of unity" $G_7$ with $p = 29$, I have to check if $g^7 \mod 29 = 1$ and if the order of $g$ is $7$, correct?

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are right, thank you.